# Keycloak - get the list of allowed special characters for user password filed

Tags: keycloak

How can I get the list of allowed special characters for user password field in Keycloak

Answer (score 4):

Looking into [Keycloak repo](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/f1e7c572da5008d2aec667642adb5cce89df25d6/server-spi-private/src/main/java/org/keycloak/policy/SpecialCharsPasswordPolicyProvider.java#L42), all characters that are not Unicode digits (`\p{N}`) or Unicode letters (`\p{L}`):

```java
!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)
```

See java method spec [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit-char-).